# Why is Swift 2.0 Compiler throwing error on UIDocuments loadFromContents

Tags: swift2, ios9, uidocument

The following UIDocument Class method override throws a compiler error:

import UIKit

class MyDocument: UIDocument {

```
override func loadFromContents(contents: AnyObject,
    ofType typeName: String) throws -> Bool {
         return true
}
```

}

Error Message:

Method does not override any method from its superclass

This didn't happen in swift 1.2, iOS 8.
I can find no documentation indicating the method has been deprecated.

Companion method "contentsForType" does not draw a compiler error.

I've spent days researching this with no resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String Type in override func loadFromContents(contents: AnyObject,
    ofType typeName: String) throws -> Bool {
         return true
}

needs to be an optional
override func loadFromContents(contents: AnyObject,
    ofType typeName: String?) throws -> Bool {
         return true
}